# I can't log in with GitHub in Android Studio. What is the problem?

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a project form Android Studio on GitHub, but for some reason I can't log in...I am sure my credentials are correct, I even changed my password, and tried both my username and my email as Login. What could be the problem here?
[image]

Comment: Most easy and straight forward way of synchronizing your project with github is to use `Github Desktop` application from their official website. No hassle of explicit plugins for IDE's

Comment: What OS are you using? Android studio could be deferring to username and password stored in credential manager (Windows) or  Keychain Access (Mac)

Comment: @Displayname I am using windows 10 pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling I know what is happening, you're entering your standard email/password combo, but the IDE is expecting you to give a token, rather than your personal password. Therefore, let's grab a token!

First, navigate to GitHub and create a personal access token, a guide on how to do that can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Once generated with all the necessary scopes, copy the token to your clipboard.

From here, you have two options, either:

Open Android Studio and click `file -> settings` then, under the drop down of `version control`, go to `GitHub`. Click the little `+` icon over in the top right and then a little login panel will appear.

Click `Use Token` found within this panel, then paste your token.

**Or**

Open the command line and go to the root directory of your project and type your command that you wish to execute e.g. `git clone www.myrepo.com`, so that you're prompted for your username and password, enter your email and then paste your token when asked for your password.

Done!

If you're not being prompted for your credentials, you will probably need to go into `Credential Manager` in Windows or `Key Chain` in iOS and remove any stored GitHub credentials that are no longer required, as Windows/iOS is using those saved details as default.

**Additional tip**

When creating your token you might want to revoke any stored personal access tokens in `GitHub`, that might have been generated by third-party plugins that you no longer need/require access.